Learning Using Celery: Without Framework
I have been coding a python based data extractor from an API for a web application. This web application uses RBMQ as a broker to pass batch details to the extractor, which fetches data to pass back to RBMQ (to decide the destination). Although I have successfully developed the extractor, my current task is to integrate it with RBMQ. However, I am now faced with new problems to solve:

Integrating the extractor with asynchronous behavior.
Ensuring the extractor can handle multiple batches (assuming that this can be solved with multiprocessing).

Someone, as amateur as myself, suggested using Celery to implement asynchronous and multiprocessing behavior. I have tried to read some documentation on Celery, but I'm having trouble making sense of it. For me, Celery seems a bit steep on the learning curve. I would appreciate some advice on how to do it. Are there better resources to learn it? or altogether Are there any better solutions available?
